# Creating stratified sample based on another dataset

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a database as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(Year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), Type = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3), Value = c(0.504376244608734, 0.544791523560323, 0.536356351248399, 
0.186754489979335, 0.0145059662169885, 0.552467068108315, 0.728991908748136, 
0.0782701833265232, 0.0770140143185365, 0.745720346755096, 0.182549844851049, 
0.0037854136407528, 0.892426526130476, 0.670307075099745, 0.0787676704471466, 
0.243642889274613, 0.61622932816441, 0.773909954748003, 0.0368627127466908, 
0.864836276200213, 0.363247130858897, 0.170719500081567, 0.458862115912474, 
0.764369844834086, 0.22138732039061, 0.950217140815184, 0.119026355092504, 
0.806698643902745, 0.809697143416323, 0.0161168403745759, 0.56149794546334, 
0.0663374185634651, 0.851044662622003, 0.144127493261805, 0.646129610173195, 
0.180326314861961, 0.346305710081752, 0.689186084156133, 0.0902438913162577, 
0.493067567084055, 0.829728867159447, 0.212655417404949, 0.873112880345332, 
0.57019799015934, 0.666924788035991, 0.421470848297274, 0.137822577124685, 
0.646797965126931, 0.00186628356193685, 0.220630784144145, 0.636097250212043, 
0.337161167241577, 0.763014675300797, 0.0290609945874959, 0.179775595422681, 
0.926270372245386, 0.14413707866326, 0.308460218540821, 0.505730133160804, 
0.92831463570813, 0.2406601397661, 0.469013177711661, 0.0514836845684897, 
0.8773477591701, 0.988870207825279, 0.0409427390691713, 0.345261503182235, 
0.457678159145652, 0.928521904779235, 0.981654149874765, 0.165376851871405, 
0.657749413049735, 0.645610554242246, 0.288901032482677, 0.903464871012278, 
0.91288926903878, 0.331819964874993, 0.451775254733976, 0.561567931867726, 
0.934770693643712, 0.0515071551015609, 0.0772762108900331, 0.233674539049138, 
0.636764452840065, 0.673165028674493, 0.806944576060158, 0.763410488346345, 
0.661058275398286, 0.275215831961986, 0.821051953775588), Value2 = c(0.898973133700585, 
0.0043728119746469, 0.90370150590114, 0.664255277142381, 0.478255150030532, 
0.428181937562552, 0.0547471373342867, 0.382060484866744, 0.467990590870777, 
0.44613758335896, 0.767317422802576, 0.378150639908367, 0.490578474103678, 
0.677901331005272, 0.287571260541928, 0.201396158908221, 0.504989505596871, 
0.854550423135574, 0.545208640791417, 0.951248990134053, 0.958420479001103, 
0.916437669811835, 0.299402641214852, 0.966388390213139, 0.511359402704707, 
0.0867219533353825, 0.88481040004275, 0.158676351804193, 0.0723357399252373, 
0.605048894989562, 0.60104443547608, 0.608164723564692, 0.309073275149768, 
0.183031315824665, 0.495737621177827, 0.981936843144856, 0.601436476710344, 
0.442362735422709, 0.497899316486054, 0.0545162134700136, 0.572666465987199, 
0.0134330483790179, 0.494252845049882, 0.752561338910785, 0.269231150235318, 
0.580397043886635, 0.00438648885146109, 0.974859546601355, 0.964309270817873, 
0.740961468264743, 0.966289928060099, 0.165450408579171, 0.457088887715921, 
0.725271665700556, 0.611801886877621, 0.693114823445831, 0.509441044895801, 
0.668642268489104, 0.0769213109282016, 0.0106313240133811, 0.653738670103508, 
0.515077318720933, 0.0355798295524966, 0.916849288357794, 0.489540407953311, 
0.355080030655249, 0.0584185346727107, 0.117505910926226, 0.840486642923002, 
0.0919621689925281, 0.513293731647231, 0.813987689492758, 0.520895630669219, 
0.417642884334403, 0.549898208275446, 0.190152036926942, 0.730222922437507, 
0.247328458018061, 0.587109508511267, 0.850096530635719, 0.929032051736368, 
0.929910983683225, 0.461558252621238, 0.106247873795127, 0.177666580357953, 
0.85962988262837, 0.531897323076434, 0.105528819826748, 0.0349104003049517, 
0.180758384726269), Value3 = c(0.728747048185938, 0.136214396563203, 
0.0552254916905935, 0.888943411458351, 0.593186561829418, 0.142192475897417, 
0.397839605231809, 0.128332683559321, 0.818143628566787, 0.675081193031822, 
0.267554700398382, 0.289692778583473, 0.395043380675461, 0.582592369450023, 
0.999361780203229, 0.421977850130829, 0.723404859329269, 0.333410997686596, 
0.545945290276875, 0.510878802866974, 0.746682101648222, 0.625853669469718, 
0.0366957172106372, 0.417685335838607, 0.106323486037796, 0.0127310987059773, 
0.291264331038641, 0.690392584005106, 0.0367947033685097, 0.287721087095362, 
0.389582158765541, 0.179954765659721, 0.688980485242488, 0.492296704771236, 
0.177765364735501, 0.311877860895471, 0.402659917512069, 0.579307427105039, 
0.588566648357923, 0.741057591300206, 0.111932877257211, 0.515443723005798, 
0.679584351614947, 0.0197622696399569, 0.0326379476305644, 0.736148474541639, 
0.0115696238487739, 0.0530159587501624, 0.710708890129421, 0.537042840144158, 
0.0277825198238522, 0.851349803530179, 0.448963399024373, 0.42841165712813, 
0.0615511042450435, 0.210541933956987, 0.983517611560273, 0.533691182135933, 
0.61993895519575, 0.136074538018663, 0.716185070081669, 0.67982888131481, 
0.186059692566576, 0.0129160598675656, 0.832257317305668, 0.0269936347869698, 
0.579065014243438, 0.857987264303428, 0.270050217297758, 0.606374993010002, 
0.565105220120649, 0.977264711860796, 0.14241840012272, 0.942496958955904, 
0.652070963472916, 0.912867524689929, 0.0249357414986835, 0.87704909395977, 
0.72849611059358, 0.525707690655331, 0.290223239565496, 0.992723233891769, 
0.178173444691217, 0.0292681960925434, 0.65696953770876, 0.452973377851251, 
0.471917712361899, 0.117830393053313, 0.126107861454795, 0.0848074010166607
)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

With the `DT` database, I want to create stratified sub samples based on the following data:

```
Ratios <- structure(list(State = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 
2007), Type = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 
1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), ratio = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 
0.45, 0.2, 0.35, 0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.05, 0.5, 0.45, 0.3, 0.5, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.35, 0.45, 0.2, 0.35, 0.2, 0.45, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6
)), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Fig 1. `Ratios`
[image: strong text]

I am trying to figure out how to approach this issue. In order to achieve the maximum possible sample size, I need to figure out the largest possible sub sample based on the ratios. Fig 1. `Ratios` shows the ratios for State A in 2005.

I first have to determine the ratios in `DT`:

```
# This is just to determine the ratio of `Type` in the data `DT`
DT_1 <- DT %>%  count(Year, Type) %>% group_by(Year)
DT_2 <- DT %>%  count(Year, Type) %>% group_by(Year) %>% mutate(n = n/sum(n))
DT_RAT <- cbind(DT_1 , DT_2)
setDT(DT_RAT)[,Year1:=NULL]
setDT(DT_RAT)[,Type1:=NULL]
rm(DT_1 , DT_2)
```

Now I should with that information create samples. I have to start with the biggest share (For State A, this is `Type==1`.) So for sample `DT_A`, half of the sample should be of `Type` = 1. From `DT_RAT` I know that this amounts to 13 observations of `Type 1` (the max amount of type 1 observations). I would like to do something like:

```
DT_A <- DT[,.SD[sample(.N, min(13,.N))],by = Type==1]
```

But I am not allowed to do that. Can anyone help me to make this happen?

EDIT:

The desired result for `DT_A` (the sub-sample of `DT` for State A) is as follows.

- 0.5 of DT_A in 2005 should consist of `Type 1` (see Fig 1)
- 0.45 of DT_A  in 2005 should consist of `Type 2`
- 0.05 of DT_A  in 2005 should consist of `Type 3`

DT has 13 observation of `Type 1` for 2005, so we take all of those. Because these 13 should be half of the sample. The total sample is 26 observations
There are also 13 observation of `Type 2` for 2005, but since only 0.45 should consist of `Type 2` we take 12. Only 5 percent should be of `Type 3`, so that is the 1 observation remaining.

- 13 = 0.5 of DT_A in 2005 should consist of `Type 1` (see Fig 1)
- 12 = 0.45 of DT_A  in 2005 should consist of `Type 2`
- 1 = 0.05 of DT_A  in 2005 should consist of `Type 3`

Comment: I think you meant `DT_1` and `DT_2` there instead of `DT_A` and `DT_B`. I am finding difficult to understand the question. How do you want to sample the dataframe `DT` ? Let's take an example of one group - `Ratios %>% filter(Year == 2005, Type == 1)` and `DT %>% filter(Year == 2005, Type == 1)`.

Comment: @RonakShah I have decided to split up the question. I posted the first part here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64445678/irregular-sampling-from-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this pipeline gives you what you need:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

DT %>% 
  count(Year, Type) %>% 
  right_join(Ratios, by = c("Year", "Type")) %>% 
  group_by(State, Year) %>% 
  mutate(sample_size = pmax(1, round(min(n / ratio) * ratio))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(State, Year, Type, sample_size) %>% 
  left_join(DT, by = c("Year","Type")) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(State, Year, Type, sample_size)) %>% 
  mutate(sample = map2(data, sample_size, ~slice_sample(.x, n = .y))) %>% 
  select(State, Year, Type, sample) %>% 
  arrange(State, Year, Type)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 27 x 4
   State  Year  Type sample          
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <list>          
 1 A      2005     1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
 2 A      2005     2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
 3 A      2005     3 <tibble [4 x 3]>
 4 A      2006     1 <tibble [4 x 3]>
 5 A      2006     2 <tibble [2 x 3]>
 6 A      2006     3 <tibble [3 x 3]>
 7 A      2007     1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
 8 A      2007     2 <tibble [1 x 3]>
 9 A      2007     3 <tibble [5 x 3]>
10 B      2005     1 <tibble [1 x 3]>
# ... with 17 more rows
```

You can further append to that pipeline a `%>% unnest(sample)`, but I will leave it like this as you never specify your expected output. This format is also easier for me to explain to you the logic behind.

The key is that you need to determine the proper sample size for each combination of `State, Year, Type`. The formula I used to determine the sample size is

```
sample_size = pmax(1, round(min(n / ratio) * ratio))
```

For example, let `n = c(13, 13, 4)`, the same numbers as your example shows. You want to slice a sample based on `ratio = c(0.5, 0.45, 0.05)`. Then, the max sample size you can have is `min(n / ratio)`, i.e. `min(c(26, 28.88889, 80)) = 26`. Any number greater than this is invalid as you don't have enough observations to sample from (for Type 2 and 3 in this case). Then we use the total sample size times the ratio to compute the sample size for each Type. We have to `round` the result as only natural numbers are allowed; we also need at least one observation for each type. That's why you see that `pmax(1, ...)`.

For the example shown in your post, this formula returns

```
> pmax(1, round(min(c(13, 13, 4) / c(0.5, 0.45, 0.05)) * c(0.5, 0.45, 0.05)))
[1] 13 12  1
```

With this setup, we can start the sampling procedure you want. We first

```
> DT %>% 
      count(Year, Type)

# A tibble: 9 x 3
   Year  Type     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1  2005     1    13
2  2005     2    13
3  2005     3     4
4  2006     1    16
5  2006     2    11
6  2006     3     3
7  2007     1    11
8  2007     2    14
9  2007     3     5
```

so that we know how many observations are there for each `Year` and `Type`. Then,

```
> DT %>% 
    count(Year, Type) %>% 
    right_join(Ratios, by = c("Year", "Type")) %>% 
    group_by(State, Year) %>% 
    mutate(sample_size = pmax(1, round(min(n / ratio) * ratio)))

# A tibble: 27 x 6
# Groups:   State, Year [9]
    Year  Type     n State ratio sample_size
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr> <dbl>       <dbl>
 1  2005     1    13 A      0.2            1
 2  2005     1    13 B      0.05           1
 3  2005     1    13 B      0.35           3
 4  2005     2    13 A      0.2            1
 5  2005     2    13 B      0.5            4
 6  2005     2    13 C      0.45           9
 7  2005     3     4 A      0.6            4
 8  2005     3     4 B      0.45           4
 9  2005     3     4 C      0.2            4
10  2006     1    16 A      0.45           4
# ... with 17 more rows
```

so that we know the proper sample size for each `Year`, `Type`, and `State`. Next,

```
DT %>% 
  count(Year, Type) %>% 
  right_join(Ratios, by = c("Year", "Type")) %>% 
  group_by(State, Year) %>% 
  mutate(sample_size = pmax(1, round(min(n / ratio) * ratio))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(State, Year, Type, sample_size) %>% 
  left_join(DT, by = c("Year","Type")) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(State, Year, Type, sample_size))

# A tibble: 27 x 5
   State  Year  Type sample_size data             
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <list>           
 1 A      2005     1           1 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 2 B      2005     1           1 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 3 B      2005     1           3 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 4 A      2005     2           1 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 5 B      2005     2           4 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 6 C      2005     2           9 <tibble [13 x 3]>
 7 A      2005     3           4 <tibble [4 x 3]> 
 8 B      2005     3           4 <tibble [4 x 3]> 
 9 C      2005     3           4 <tibble [4 x 3]> 
10 A      2006     1           4 <tibble [16 x 3]>
# ... with 17 more rows
```

so that the sample size and data are matched for each `Year` and `Type`. Last, we take a sample of the data for each group using the `slice_sample` function, select the columns we need, and then arrange the data for display.

```
DT %>% 
  count(Year, Type) %>% 
  right_join(Ratios, by = c("Year", "Type")) %>% 
  group_by(State, Year) %>% 
  mutate(sample_size = pmax(1, round(min(n / ratio) * ratio))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(State, Year, Type, sample_size) %>% 
  left_join(DT, by = c("Year","Type")) %>% 
  nest(data = -c(State, Year, Type, sample_size)) %>% 
  mutate(sample = map2(data, sample_size, ~slice_sample(.x, n = .y))) %>% 
  select(State, Year, Type, sample) %>% 
  arrange(State, Year, Type)
```

The output of this pipeline is shown at the beginning of this post. I think you can also achieve the same result in a `data.table` way. However, I will leave it like this as this pipeline is better for illustration purpose.

Comment: Thank you for this absolutely amazing answer. I have been trying to take it apart a little bit, because I was getting errors towards the end of your code. I separated the code now up to and including `nest`. Then I get the error: `Error: Problem with mutate() input sample.
x n must be a non-missing positive number.
i Input sample is map2(data, sample_size, ~slice_sample(.x, n = .y))` Which is I guess because my actual data has NA's . Do you know of any way to cope with this?

Comment: @Tom My best guess is that there are `NA`s in `n`. Perhaps some `Type` does not exist for a certain `Year`, but you specify a `Ratio` for that missing `Type`. Then, when we try to `right_join`, `NA`s are introduced in the column `n`. Try adding this line `drop_na() %>% `in between `right_join(...)` and `group_by(...)` and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have started removing "dead wood" in between the steps you described and it seems to be going much better now.

Comment: I got it to work! I am extremely grateful for all your help!