# Irregular sampling from data

Tags: r, data.table, sample

I have a database as follows:

```
DT <- structure(list(Year = c(2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
2005, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 
2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 
2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007, 2007), Type = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3), Value = c(0.504376244608734, 0.544791523560323, 0.536356351248399, 
0.186754489979335, 0.0145059662169885, 0.552467068108315, 0.728991908748136, 
0.0782701833265232, 0.0770140143185365, 0.745720346755096, 0.182549844851049, 
0.0037854136407528, 0.892426526130476, 0.670307075099745, 0.0787676704471466, 
0.243642889274613, 0.61622932816441, 0.773909954748003, 0.0368627127466908, 
0.864836276200213, 0.363247130858897, 0.170719500081567, 0.458862115912474, 
0.764369844834086, 0.22138732039061, 0.950217140815184, 0.119026355092504, 
0.806698643902745, 0.809697143416323, 0.0161168403745759, 0.56149794546334, 
0.0663374185634651, 0.851044662622003, 0.144127493261805, 0.646129610173195, 
0.180326314861961, 0.346305710081752, 0.689186084156133, 0.0902438913162577, 
0.493067567084055, 0.829728867159447, 0.212655417404949, 0.873112880345332, 
0.57019799015934, 0.666924788035991, 0.421470848297274, 0.137822577124685, 
0.646797965126931, 0.00186628356193685, 0.220630784144145, 0.636097250212043, 
0.337161167241577, 0.763014675300797, 0.0290609945874959, 0.179775595422681, 
0.926270372245386, 0.14413707866326, 0.308460218540821, 0.505730133160804, 
0.92831463570813, 0.2406601397661, 0.469013177711661, 0.0514836845684897, 
0.8773477591701, 0.988870207825279, 0.0409427390691713, 0.345261503182235, 
0.457678159145652, 0.928521904779235, 0.981654149874765, 0.165376851871405, 
0.657749413049735, 0.645610554242246, 0.288901032482677, 0.903464871012278, 
0.91288926903878, 0.331819964874993, 0.451775254733976, 0.561567931867726, 
0.934770693643712, 0.0515071551015609, 0.0772762108900331, 0.233674539049138, 
0.636764452840065, 0.673165028674493, 0.806944576060158, 0.763410488346345, 
0.661058275398286, 0.275215831961986, 0.821051953775588), Value2 = c(0.898973133700585, 
0.0043728119746469, 0.90370150590114, 0.664255277142381, 0.478255150030532, 
0.428181937562552, 0.0547471373342867, 0.382060484866744, 0.467990590870777, 
0.44613758335896, 0.767317422802576, 0.378150639908367, 0.490578474103678, 
0.677901331005272, 0.287571260541928, 0.201396158908221, 0.504989505596871, 
0.854550423135574, 0.545208640791417, 0.951248990134053, 0.958420479001103, 
0.916437669811835, 0.299402641214852, 0.966388390213139, 0.511359402704707, 
0.0867219533353825, 0.88481040004275, 0.158676351804193, 0.0723357399252373, 
0.605048894989562, 0.60104443547608, 0.608164723564692, 0.309073275149768, 
0.183031315824665, 0.495737621177827, 0.981936843144856, 0.601436476710344, 
0.442362735422709, 0.497899316486054, 0.0545162134700136, 0.572666465987199, 
0.0134330483790179, 0.494252845049882, 0.752561338910785, 0.269231150235318, 
0.580397043886635, 0.00438648885146109, 0.974859546601355, 0.964309270817873, 
0.740961468264743, 0.966289928060099, 0.165450408579171, 0.457088887715921, 
0.725271665700556, 0.611801886877621, 0.693114823445831, 0.509441044895801, 
0.668642268489104, 0.0769213109282016, 0.0106313240133811, 0.653738670103508, 
0.515077318720933, 0.0355798295524966, 0.916849288357794, 0.489540407953311, 
0.355080030655249, 0.0584185346727107, 0.117505910926226, 0.840486642923002, 
0.0919621689925281, 0.513293731647231, 0.813987689492758, 0.520895630669219, 
0.417642884334403, 0.549898208275446, 0.190152036926942, 0.730222922437507, 
0.247328458018061, 0.587109508511267, 0.850096530635719, 0.929032051736368, 
0.929910983683225, 0.461558252621238, 0.106247873795127, 0.177666580357953, 
0.85962988262837, 0.531897323076434, 0.105528819826748, 0.0349104003049517, 
0.180758384726269), Value3 = c(0.728747048185938, 0.136214396563203, 
0.0552254916905935, 0.888943411458351, 0.593186561829418, 0.142192475897417, 
0.397839605231809, 0.128332683559321, 0.818143628566787, 0.675081193031822, 
0.267554700398382, 0.289692778583473, 0.395043380675461, 0.582592369450023, 
0.999361780203229, 0.421977850130829, 0.723404859329269, 0.333410997686596, 
0.545945290276875, 0.510878802866974, 0.746682101648222, 0.625853669469718, 
0.0366957172106372, 0.417685335838607, 0.106323486037796, 0.0127310987059773, 
0.291264331038641, 0.690392584005106, 0.0367947033685097, 0.287721087095362, 
0.389582158765541, 0.179954765659721, 0.688980485242488, 0.492296704771236, 
0.177765364735501, 0.311877860895471, 0.402659917512069, 0.579307427105039, 
0.588566648357923, 0.741057591300206, 0.111932877257211, 0.515443723005798, 
0.679584351614947, 0.0197622696399569, 0.0326379476305644, 0.736148474541639, 
0.0115696238487739, 0.0530159587501624, 0.710708890129421, 0.537042840144158, 
0.0277825198238522, 0.851349803530179, 0.448963399024373, 0.42841165712813, 
0.0615511042450435, 0.210541933956987, 0.983517611560273, 0.533691182135933, 
0.61993895519575, 0.136074538018663, 0.716185070081669, 0.67982888131481, 
0.186059692566576, 0.0129160598675656, 0.832257317305668, 0.0269936347869698, 
0.579065014243438, 0.857987264303428, 0.270050217297758, 0.606374993010002, 
0.565105220120649, 0.977264711860796, 0.14241840012272, 0.942496958955904, 
0.652070963472916, 0.912867524689929, 0.0249357414986835, 0.87704909395977, 
0.72849611059358, 0.525707690655331, 0.290223239565496, 0.992723233891769, 
0.178173444691217, 0.0292681960925434, 0.65696953770876, 0.452973377851251, 
0.471917712361899, 0.117830393053313, 0.126107861454795, 0.0848074010166607
)), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

From this `DT`, I want to sample by group. Something like:

```
DT_new <- setDT(DT)[,.SD[sample(.N, min(3,.N))],by = Type]
```

But instead of getting three draws from each type, I would like specify how many draws of each type I want, based on for example this data:

```
Ratio <- structure(list(Type = c(1, 2, 3), n = c(13L, 13L, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
    Year = c(2005, 2006, 2007), .rows = list(1:3, 4:6, 7:9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

[image: Ratio]

Desired result:

```
DT_A <- setDT(DT)[,.SD[sample(.N, min(13,.N))],by = Type]
DT_B <- setDT(DT)[,.SD[sample(.N, min(13,.N))],by = Type]
DT_C <- setDT(DT)[,.SD[sample(.N, min(4,.N))],by = Type]
DT_A <- DT_A[1:13,]
DT_B <- DT_B[14:26,]
DT_C <- DT_C[9:12,]
DT_new <- rbind(DT_A, DT_B, DT_C)
table(DT_new$Type)

 1  2  3 
13 13  4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can join `Ratio` to `DT` and then directly use `n` in the sample command.

I add an `ID` column to make it clear that it works. You can, of course, drop the `ID` and `n` columns at the end.

```
DT[, ID := 1:.N, by = Type][Ratio, on = "Type"][, .SD[sample(.N, min(n[1], .N)), ], by = Type]
#     Type Year      Value      Value2     Value3 ID  n
#  1:    1 2006 0.64612961 0.495737621 0.17776536 18 13
#  2:    1 2005 0.18675449 0.664255277 0.88894341  4 13
#  3:    1 2006 0.57019799 0.752561339 0.01976227 27 13
#  4:    1 2006 0.82972887 0.572666466 0.11193288 24 13
#  5:    1 2006 0.87311288 0.494252845 0.67958435 26 13
#  6:    1 2007 0.46901318 0.515077319 0.67982888 31 13
#  7:    1 2006 0.09024389 0.497899316 0.58856665 22 13
#  8:    1 2005 0.50437624 0.898973134 0.72874705  1 13
#  9:    1 2005 0.54479152 0.004372812 0.13621440  2 13
# 10:    1 2005 0.53635635 0.903701506 0.05522549  3 13
# 11:    1 2007 0.05148368 0.035579830 0.18605969 32 13
# 12:    1 2007 0.45767816 0.117505911 0.85798726 37 13
# 13:    1 2006 0.14412749 0.183031316 0.49229670 17 13
# 14:    2 2005 0.07876767 0.287571261 0.99936178  2 13
# 15:    2 2007 0.90346487 0.549898208 0.65207096 28 13
# 16:    2 2005 0.76436984 0.966388390 0.41768534 11 13
# 17:    2 2005 0.67030708 0.677901331 0.58259237  1 13
# 18:    2 2006 0.33716117 0.165450409 0.85134980 19 13
# 19:    2 2007 0.64561055 0.520895631 0.14241840 26 13
# 20:    2 2006 0.63609725 0.966289928 0.02778252 18 13
# 21:    2 2007 0.56156793 0.587109509 0.72849611 32 13
# 22:    2 2007 0.67316503 0.177666580 0.65696954 38 13
# 23:    2 2007 0.93477069 0.850096531 0.52570769 33 13
# 24:    2 2007 0.23367454 0.461558253 0.17817344 36 13
# 25:    2 2007 0.63676445 0.106247874 0.02926820 37 13
# 26:    2 2006 0.92627037 0.693114823 0.21054193 23 13
# 27:    3 2005 0.80669864 0.158676352 0.69039258  2  4
# 28:    3 2006 0.92831464 0.010631324 0.13607454  7  4
# 29:    3 2007 0.76341049 0.531897323 0.47191771  9  4
# 30:    3 2005 0.01611684 0.605048895 0.28772109  4  4
#     Type Year      Value      Value2     Value3 ID  n
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is much better!

Comment: I have one more small question. I figured that I would like the code to additionally say to only sample from `Year==2005`. I have been trying to see how to adapt your solution, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: So you want to sample from 2005 but keep the full data from other years?

Comment: No, actually only keep the sampled observations from 2005.

Comment: Stick `DT[Year == 2005, ]` on the very front, before the ID column. Just a normal subset. You could stick it at the end, but then you still do all the work of sampling each year. Put it at the beginning and you'll only do the work work on 2005 data.

Comment: Hahaha okay. I was kind of hoping that is was somewhere within the code, as I was hoping to expand this example to a slightly more complicated one (where `Ratio` also has a column specifying `Year`). I wanted, instead of only on `Type`, to make it possible to do it with `Year` and `Type`.

Comment: Sure, you can add a `Year` column to `Ratio` and join `on = c("Year", "Type")`

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much! (I actually managed to forget to add the year column in `Ratio` haha)

Comment: I think in case I want to join on `year` and `Type` the last `by` part of the formula also requires `by = c("year","Type")` right (in addition to the `on = c("Year", "Type")`? In any case, it works perfectly now for me. Once again, thank you very much.